# Looping through text items an illustrator page

Tags: adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I have an illustrator document with various text and path items on it. I want to loop through all the text items and change the colour of them, and a couple of attributes. Then depending on the items name I want to group it with other items with the same name. I have a script that almost works. The problem is that it leaves some items out, or ignores them inconsistently. Sometimes it effects them, other times it just ignores them. Any help appreciated, script below

```
//Selects the graph before to scale them and turns off the pixel align so that values of 1 decimal place can be applied to strokes
doc.selectObjectsOnActiveArtboard();  
var sel = doc.selection;
sel.pixelAligned=false

var item

var xLabels = layer.groupItems.add();  //create group for xAxis
xLabels.name="xLabels"
var yLabels = layer.groupItems.add();  //create group for xAxis
yLabels.name="yLabels"
var yTicks = layer.groupItems.add();  //create group for xAxis
yTicks.name="yTicks"

//Loops through  ungrouped text items and set horizontal scale, spot black and tabular lining on figures
for (var i = 0; i < layer.textFrames.length; i++) {
    item=layer.textFrames[i];
    $.writeln (item)
    item.textRange.characterAttributes.textFont = textFonts.getByName("Metric-Regular");
    item.textRange.characterAttributes.figureStyle=FigureStyleType.TABULAR
    item.textRange.characterAttributes.fillColor=myBlack;

    //move labels on xAxis into the same group
    if (item.name=="xAxisLabel") {
         item.moveToEnd(xLabels);
     }

    //move labels on yAxis into the same group
     if (item.name=="yAxisLabel") {
            item.moveToEnd(yLabels);
     };

 };

for (var i = 0; i < layer.pathItems.length; i++) {
    item=layer.pathItems[i];

     if (item.name=="yAxisTick") {
            item.moveToEnd(yTicks);
     };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

---

The solution to this is to reverse the loop. Basically as you move the items into a group it changes the number of 'loose' text items on the page so your loop length effectively changes mid way through. Good visual explanation to this can be found at https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2171307 where I also posted the question